# How to open terminal inside a folder in Nautilus, so that the folder is the current location?

Tags: 12.10, command-line, nautilus, gnome-terminal, dolphin

In Dolphin with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> Terminal is opened from current location in Dolphin. Is there any similar functionality in Nautilus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

After you'll get a new entry in the contextual menu of nautilus (you probably need to relaunch your session to get it work).